# How to print columns containing sentences without losing everything after the first word in awk printf?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a command

> paste dataset1.txt dataset2.txt | head -7 | cut -f3,5 | awk '{printf
>   "%-20s %s \n", $1, $0}'

to display two columns from two separated files in formatted manner. But the problem is the 2nd column(or column no. 5 which I got from using `cut -f3,5` consists of sentences not single words(like a country name) as you can see below it is a `Description` so it doesn't display anything except the first word like for eg, `Defines` in the `2nd and 3rd row`.

A undesired alternative I used (*given below*) was $0 but it display all the columns. Is there a way I can modify the command above so as to display the `Description` as it is without getting redundant columns and without getting only single words?

[image: Output of the command]

Comment: Posting samples in images is NEVER encouraged, please add samples in code tags with your efforts.

Comment: If you mean you want to remove the first field/column, use `$1=""` and the content of `$0` will be changed accordingly.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Basically you are suggesting `awk '{printf "%-20s", $1;$1="";printf "%s \n", $0}'`, is that right?

Comment: @vdavid I don't understand the question at all I just happen to know that if you assign to any of `$0` thru `$NF`, the current line is reparsed and all the fields recalculated and I happen to guess that's what OP wants. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: Edited. Sorry for the trouble. Hopefully it's easier to understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are using is:

```
paste file1 file2 | cut -f3,5 | awk '{printf "%-20s %s \n", $1, $0}'
```

There is, however, something interesting here.

- The command `paste` writes lines consisting of the sequentially corresponding lines from each file, separated by **TABs**, to standard output.
- The command `cut` has **TAB** as a default delimiter for input and output.

So, in the end, all that needs to be done is tell awk to use TAB as a delimiter, instead of its default *any form of whitespace*:

```
paste file1 file2 | cut -f3,5 | awk -F'\t' '{printf "%-20s %s \n", $1, $2}'
```

but actually, we can put the cut together with the `awk`

```
paste file1 file2 | awk -F'\t' '{printf "%-20s %s \n", $3, $5}'
```

**Note:** we can probably even merge `file1` and `file2` in the `awk` command line. `paste` in `awk` would look like:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}(NR==FNR){a[NR]=$0;next}{print a[NR], $0}' file1 file2
```

So the while line could be written as:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
     (NR==FNR){a[NR]=$0;next}
     {$0=a[NR] OFS $0}
     { printf "%-20s %s \n", $3, $5 }' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question, but the final line implies you are trying to get rid of an unwanted column in a file using `awk`. So, the following shows how to do that.

Let's assume you have made a mistake somewhere in your data processing and your file `fruits.txt` looks like this:

```
apple orange elephant banana nectarine
guava kiwi mouse grape pear
```

You obviously want to get rid of field 3, so you can delete `$3` which will cause the line to be parsed again:

```
awk '{$3=""; print}' fruits.txt
```

**Output**

```
apple orange  banana nectarine
guava kiwi  grape pear
```

Hopefully you can adapt that to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of suggesting how to better write what you want, this answer is to only respond to your straight forward question

> So my question is how to remove a column from the set of columns - $0?

```
awk '{x=$1; $1=""; printf "%-20s %s \n", x, $0}'

> echo "this is a multiple word sentence" | awk '{x=$1; $1=""; printf "%-20s %s \n", x, $0}'
this                  is a multiple word sentence
```